# How to pass object of arrays in class component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access this object of arrays using `switch case` in the
`condition` function and display the result in the `items` class.

```
import React from "react";

class Conditional extends React .Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
       this .state = [
      {
    id: 1,
    name : "John",
    title: "Doe",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name : "Peter",
    title: "Parker",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name : "Richard",
    title: "Doe",
  },
];
  }

condition() {
let length = this . state .length;
console.log(length);
  }

  render() {
     return <div>{ <item data={this .condition()}/> }

  </div>;
  }
 }


class item extends React .Component {
 render() {
   return (
  <div>
    <p>{this .props .data}</p>
  </div>
);

  }

  export default Conditional ;
```

Comment: Try to link some code to see your progress so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow
Please provide your code, along with error and your expected result
please provide a [minimum reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
See [How do I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I uploaded the code can anybody help me with it?